# Curl link for cudann download

Tags: nvidia, curl

So previously, I was using this [link](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/redist/cudnn/v7.0.5/cudnn-9.0-linux-x64-v7.tgz) to download cudann 7.0.5 using the curl command. However, I know need a slightly newer version and I found the [link](https://developer.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/cudnn/secure/v7.3.0/prod/9.0_2018920/cudnn-9.0-linux-x64-v7.3.0.29):

But I'm not able to download this link using `curl` because of login requirements. How can I bypass this? I can't manually download because I'm sshing into a server. Hence, I have to use the `curl` command.

(I also noticed that the two links are slightly different in address paths. However, I'm not able to find the 7.3 version with the same path as the first link. If I could find out how to access all the versions through the same path as the first link, that'd be ideal.)

Comment: Just an idea - maybe you could download the file to your local machine then `scp` it to the remote machine.

Comment: @wjandrea I've fixed the link. True I could scp it, but I'm trying to create a docker